# Converting date.time to increasing hours in r

Tags: r

If I have dataframe "time3", how can I convert the datetime to hours? I'm looking to set the first element in "time3" as the reference time point (let's say -11 hours), and then increase the elements of the dataframe by the hours elapsed. The output should look like the dataframe "output".

```
first <- as.POSIXct(strptime("2003/01/01", "%Y/%m/%d"))
last <- as.POSIXct(strptime("2005/12/31", "%Y/%m/%d"))
dt <- last-first

nSamples <- 5
set.seed(1)
time1 <- data.frame((rDates <- first + runif(nSamples) * as.numeric(dt)))
time2 <- time1 + 1000000
time3 <- rbind(time1, time2)

output <- data.frame(-11:1000)
```

Comment: It's not clear how you expect to get your output from the input you gave. Are you just looking for a sequence of times one hour apart, or are you looking to have each time in `time3` represented as a number of hours since the starting time? If it's the latter, your input here won't give you the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired output isn't really clear from the question. The input times are not sequentially arranged because they are drawn from a uniform distribution without being cumulatively summed, plus there's only 10 of them, so there's no way to convert them to the sequence -11:1000. I'm guessing you just meant this as a rough illustration of the *format* of the input and output.

In case I've got this wrong and you're just looking for a sequence of times starting from `first` and ending at `last` you would do:

```
seq.POSIXt(first, last, by = "hour")
```

If you want to know the difference in hours between each entry compared to the first entry, you would do:

```
as.numeric(difftime(time3[[1]], time3[1,1], units = "hours"))
#>  [1]   0.00000000   0.03242880   0.09348401   0.19548765  -0.01941396 277.777777
#>  [7] 277.81020658 277.87126179 277.97326543 277.75836381
```

And if you only want the complete number of hours that have passed, you take the floor of this:

```
floor(as.numeric(difftime(time3[[1]], time3[1,1], units = "hours")))
#>  [1]   0   0   0   0  -1 277 277 277 277 277
```

And if you want to set the initial time to -11 and compare everything from there, you can do:

```
floor(as.numeric(difftime(time3[[1]], time3[1,1], units = "hours"))) - 11
#> [1] -11 -11 -11 -11 -12 266 266 266 266 266
```

Comment: Sorry about the output confusion. You were right about the output being only an example of an output, not the actual output from what I had submitted. Any how, the combination of the first and third solution was what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking to compute the time elapsed from a reference point and to display these difference as hours rather than the default seconds. Using your example data with a slight change from `rDates <-` to `rDates =`, i.e.:

```r
time1 <- data.frame(rDates = first + runif(nSamples) * as.numeric(dt))
```

I think `hms::as_hms` might be a good option for you:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(hms)

time3 %>% 
    mutate(tdiff = as_hms(rDates - rDates[1])) %>% 
    arrange(tdiff)

#### Output ####
                rDates             tdiff
1  2003-01-01 00:03:40 - 00:01:09.890272
2  2003-01-01 00:04:50   00:00:00.000000 # <- reference
3  2003-01-01 00:06:47   00:01:56.743684
4  2003-01-01 00:10:27   00:05:36.542447
5  2003-01-01 00:16:34   00:11:43.755544
6  2003-01-12 13:50:20  277:45:30.109728
7  2003-01-12 13:51:30  277:46:40.000000
8  2003-01-12 13:53:27  277:48:36.743684
9  2003-01-12 13:57:07  277:52:16.542447
10 2003-01-12 14:03:14  277:58:23.755544
```

`lubridate::seconds_to_period` might also be an option, although it's not exactly what you asked for:

```r
library(lubridate)

time3 %>% 
    mutate(tdiff = seconds_to_period(rDates - rDates[1])) %>% 
    arrange(tdiff)

#### Output ####
                rDates                         tdiff
1  2003-01-01 00:03:40        -1M -9.89027166366577S
2  2003-01-01 00:04:50                            0S # <- reference
3  2003-01-12 13:57:07 11d 13H 52M 16.5424467325211S
4  2003-01-12 14:03:14 11d 13H 58M 23.7555438280106S
5  2003-01-12 13:50:20 11d 13H 45M 30.1097283363342S
6  2003-01-01 00:10:27          5M 36.5424467325211S
7  2003-01-12 13:53:27 11d 13H 48M 36.7436839342117S
8  2003-01-12 13:51:30               11d 13H 46M 40S
9  2003-01-01 00:16:34         11M 43.7555438280106S
10 2003-01-01 00:06:47          1M 56.7436839342117S
```